# Is it simply an issue of an awkward phrase or are there specific grammatical problems?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

A question on a grammar/writing test is as follows:

> Wilmers and Estes caution, however, that **having more otters** will not automatically solve the problem of higher levels of carbon dioxide in the air.**

The question asks if the bold phrase should be changed or not to the following:

> A) No change
>   B) increasing the otter population
>   C) the otters multiplying
>   D) having more otters than other locations

The correct answer is B) increasing the otter population, which seems right to me, but why? Is there a reason beyond "because it sounds better?"

**The question is from a passage about how otters eat sea urchins, which in turn consume kelp forests, forests that absorb carbon dioxide in the air. Thus, the presence of sea otters preserves the kelp forests that lower carbon dioxide.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about SAT Practice Test 2, Section 2, Question 32. The College Board's own explanation is,

> Choice B is the best answer because its clear wording and formal tone correspond with the passage’s established style.
>
> Choices A, C, and D are incorrect because each contains vague language that is inconsistent with the passage’s clear wording and formal tone.

What might the CB find "vague" in choice A? While the meaning of "increasing the otter population" is unambiguous even without contextual clues, "having more otters" requires context to understand. (There may be more to it than that. To tell you the truth I'm having a hard time imagining an SAT-style sentence that uses "having" as a gerund.)

Neither C nor D has quite the right meaning: Otters might multiply, that is reproduce, without otter population increasing. One location might have more otters than another without otter population increasing.